# How to select f POSIXlt data that falls into a certain timeframe?

Tags: r, date, selection, numeric, posixlt

I try to analyze some data imported from a .csv spreadsheet.
To analyze the data I need to restrict my sample to a certain timeframe (from d.m.Y H:M:S to d.m.Y H:M:S). The time data is in format `POSIXlt` (converted from `character` as original input). I am looking for suggestions how to cut this, since my approach does not result in a dataframe, but an empty integer.

```
    > dF<-NE2A1[1:5,]
    > dF
      Time X.1.oC.0 X.2.pf..do.. X.HK.Temp.oC
      1  18.05.2013 08:29:47  4.93333        1.577        13.80
      2                            NA           NA           NA
      3  18.05.2013 09:00:09  5.10333        1.583        22.63
      4  18.05.2013 10:00:08  5.39333        1.589        31.10
      5  18.05.2013 11:00:07  5.67333        1.593        25.88
      #Converting to POSIXlt format.
      > dF$Time<-strptime(dF$Time, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
      #My attempt to select data from a certain timeframe:
      > dF.cut<-which(with(dF, (dF$Time>"2013-05-18 09:00:00"))&(dF$Time<"2013-05-18 11:00:07"))
```

dails. As it results in the following dF.cut:

```
     > dF.cut

     integer(0)
```

Does anybody know a workaround for this problem?
I made sure, that `dF$Time` is of type `charakter`
not `factor`.

Comment: How about quotes around dates?

Comment: Thank you! Edited that. However, the resulting dataframe is empty, although it ought contain some values. Suggstions?

Comment: Honestly, I thought it was the only required fix. Another possible problem is that your `Time` column is treated like a factor instead of a character vector, with empty string instead of `NA` (like in the second line). `str(dF)` will give a hint what it is.